# How can an application retrieve the LinkedIn connections of its users?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'd like to create a web application that could retrieve its users' LinkedIn network (1st degree connections). Can this be done using the "Sign In with LinkedIn" feature or any available LinkedIn API or Partner Program? Ideally, using the "Sign In with LinkedIn" to register to the web application will retrieve the user's LinkedIn basic profile (incl. name, last name, company, current position, primary email address) but also its 1st degree connections (also including their first name, last name, company, current position, primary email address). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinkedIn API to get 1st degree connection once user grants access from OAuth.

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api).